# Magento 2.1.2 problem with instantiating TotalsItemExtensionInterface

Tags: php, magento-2.1, autoloader

I have a problem with instantiating **\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemExtensionInterface**

Below is my code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout;


class ShippingInformationManagement extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement
{
    private $totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\PaymentMethodManagementInterface $paymentMethodManagement
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentDetailsFactory $paymentDetailsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartTotalRepositoryInterface $cartTotalsRepository
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteAddressValidator $addressValidator
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector $totalsCollector
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\PaymentMethodManagementInterface $paymentMethodManagement,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentDetailsFactory $paymentDetailsFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartTotalRepositoryInterface $cartTotalsRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteAddressValidator $addressValidator,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector $totalsCollector,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory $totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory

    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentMethodManagement,
            $paymentDetailsFactory,
            $cartTotalsRepository,
            $quoteRepository,
            $addressValidator,
            $logger,
            $addressRepository,
            $scopeConfig,
            $totalsCollector
        );

        $this->totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory = $totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function saveAddressInformation(
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $paymentDetails = parent::saveAddressInformation($cartId, $addressInformation);
        $extensionAttribute = $this->totalsItemExtensionInterfaceFactory->create();
    }
}
```

But i have an error:

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemExtensionInterface in
>   /var/www/project/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
>   on line 73

Where is the problem? I see that interface **TotalsItemExtensionInterface** is generated correctly in directory **var/generation/Magento/Quote/Api/Data**
Below is what has been generated there

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Quote\Api\Data;

/**
 * ExtensionInterface class for @see \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemInterface
 */
interface TotalsItemExtensionInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesInterface
{
}
```